# Calling super() in constructor

Tags: java, constructor

I just used Eclipse's 'generate constructor using fields' function and it provided me with the following constructur:

```
public Credentials(String userName, String password) {
    super();
    this.userName = userName;
    this.password = password;
}
```

The `Credentials` class does not explicitly extend another class so it extends `Object` I guess. 
What is the `super();` call good for?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Confused with Constructors and Subclasses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22060217/confused-with-constructors-and-subclasses)

Comment: It will not make any impact at all as Object class dont initilise any   thing in default constructor

Comment: super() is a special use of the super keyword where you call a parameterless parent constructor. In general, the super keyword can be used to call overridden methods, access hidden fields or invoke a superclass's constructor.

Comment: in this case it will do nothing

Comment: JFYI, every class extends from the `Object` class implicitly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you were to define your constructor as:

```
public Credentials(String userName, String password) {
    this.userName = userName;
    this.password = password;
}
```

Then the compiler will add an implicit call to the superclass constructor anyway, so this doesn't make ***ANY*** difference to the compiled code.

> The Credentials class does not explicitly extend another class so it extends Object I guess. What is the super(); call good for?

But your class implicitly extends `Object`, so a call to `Object()` will be made.

Comment: Damn. Your adherence to semantic absolutes has got me all hot and bothered. I'll do it @Keppil.

Comment: Yeah I think the jokes over. I've gone for a much more subtle alternative @Keppil

Answer (score 1):

The `super` keyword is a reference to the "enclosing" instance of the current superclass.

You can use it to either access the superclass's methods or fields (in case they are visible). If your class does not have a superclass (specified by `class Credentials extends SuperclassName`), the superclass is `Object` automatically.

`super()` as a method call invokes the superclass's constructor (the one with no arguments). You can only call in you own class's constructor(s), not in any other method.

Example:

```
class A {
  private String m_name;
  public A(String name){
    m_name = name;
  }
}

class B extends A {
  public B(String firstName, String lastName){
    //this calls the constructor of A
    super(firstName + " " + lastName);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

super() calls the parent constructor with no arguments.

To use if for arguments for example super(your argument) it will call the constructor that accepts one parameter of the type of argument (if extists).

Also it can be used to call methods from the parent. I.e. super.yourMethod()

Comment: any additional information that improve the answer will be appreciate

Answer (score 0):

`super()` calls parent class constructor, if you won't add this line, non arg constructor will be called by default.

If parent class does not have non-args constructor and you won't call other constructor, your code will not compile